How is the grammar of "sah mich im Liegen dem starren Blick einer Puppe ausgesetzt" explained?
This sentence appears in Der Anschlag by Stephen King, translated by Wolf Bergner,

Ich stolperte über den Sandkasten mitten im Garten der Dunnings, knallte der Länge nach hin und sah mich im Liegen dem starren Blick einer Puppe ausgesetzt, die ein Diadem und sonst nichts trug.

The grammar in this part of the sentence

sah mich im Liegen dem starren Blick einer Puppe ausgesetzt

does not seem complete, as if it should be 2 separate phrases,something like

sah mich im Liegen und war mich dem starren Blick einer Puppe ausgesetzt

How is the original sentence correct German? And why does it have only one "mich"? Shouldn't there be a mich for the im Liegen, and then another mich to be consistent with the form given by DWDS for aussetzen?

sich, jmdn., etw. einer unangenehmen, schädlichen Sache aussetzen

This is the original English from which it was translated:

I tripped over the sandbox in the middle of the Dunning backyard, fell full length, and found myself face-to-face with a blank-eyed doll wearing a tiara and nothing else.


"war mich … ausgesetzt" would definitely be ungrammatical, would need to be "war … ausgesetzt"

The verb sehen can be used as a copula in German. Its predicative must be a participle phrase, and most commonly, it's reflexive.

Er ist Wind und Wetter ausgeliefert.
Er sieht sich Wind und Wetter ausgeliefert.

The meaning is similar to sein but it's not a fact but a feeling. Often one of being a victim of circumstances.
You can use a similar phrase with nouns:

Er sieht sich als Sieger.

This means it's not a fact, no one declared him winner. It's only his feeling.


sah mich im Liegen dem starren Blick einer Puppe ausgesetzt
sah mich … ausgesetzt

So this is all about his feeling that he was exposed to the stare of the doll.

im Liegen

This is an additional adverbial that tells a circumstance.

I can't seem to find this meaning in any of the dictionaries I checked, but "sich sehen" means "to find oneself [in some situation]". Its use, however, seems to be confined to very few fixed expressions, one of which is "sich ausgesetzt sehen" (to be met with, lit. to find oneself exposed to).
Others are "sahen sich konfrontiert", "sahen sich gezwungen/genötigt", "sahen sich umzingelt/umstellt" etc.
Another meaning of "sich sehen" is the "see yourself" as in:

Wo sehen Sie sich in 5 Jahren? Where do you see yourself in five years' time?

(I myself have not encountered this outside of the context of recruiting.)

So the original phrase means, "I found myself exposed to being lying down (and) to the stare of a doll"? That seems very odd. Do Germans find themselves exposed to lying down? I would think that Germans would, like English speakers, find themselves lying down and then also exposed to the stare of a doll. The phrase still does not make sense to me, even given the idiomatic (and undocumented) "sich ausgesetzt sehen".

It's "im Liegen" which means "while lying" so the meaning is "I found myself exposed to the stare of a doll while [I was] lying".
